# Как добавить собственный текст в Запрос формы на Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel5

Подскажите пожалуйста - у меня есть мой собственный запрос формы - как добавить собственное сообщение, чтобы выводилось вместо стандартного при ошибке Валидации ?

```php
<?php

namespace Corp\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        return $validator;

    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'desc' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо дописать метод `messages()` который возвращает массив с сообщениями валидации, например:

```
public function messages() {
   return [
       'title.required' => 'Заголовок обязательен',
       'title.max' => 'Заголовок максимум 255 символов!',
       'desc.required' => 'Заполните описание'
   ];
}
```

Сообщения валидации пишем через точку где `title` это поле а `required` правило

Comment: Спасибо большое... странно, эти правила написаны в официальных источниках и документациях, а я их просто не дочитал! Спасибо за отзывчивость!